# About Validation and the AJAX Tab Container/Tab Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabpanel

I have an ajax tab container and it have 3 tab panel,

For example, First panel to insert data, second panel to update data, third panel to delete data

At the first panel (insertion), I give an error handling using Required Field validator

At the second panel, I don't give this error handling

Then I'm trying to update a data, but it can't do that, because of the first panel have an error handling and it runs besides I click at the update panel.

Shortly, my problem is when I click update button at the update panel, it doesn't do anything because this button trigger the required field validator (error handling) at the first panel.

So, could You give me solution how to solve this problem? So the button could work alone on each panel?

I have tried to give attribute false to required validator and when I click insert button it made the validator set to true, but it's not work.

Comment: Please don't just add stuff like "ASP.NET C#" to the ends of your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: And don't change the title to "solved", when you accept an answer it's marked as green and everyone knows its solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create groups for your validators and submit buttons. On each tab set the **ValidationGroup** attribute of all the validators and the submit button. For example, on the insert tab set this property on you RequiredFieldValidators and "Insert" button:

```
ValidationGroup="InsertData"
```

Do the same on each tab using a different ValidationGroup. You can find an example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx